# Parsing the value to the function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The problem is that `id`, `start` and `end` are getting the value `2` inside `updateLine`. I can see this while debugging the code in Zend Studio. What is the reason for this?

UPDATE: I need to be able to parse string values to the function `updateLine`.

```
include_once 'include/connect_db.php';

$id = '2230';
$start = '2012-10-02 11:36:13';
$end = '2012-10-02 11:36:13';

$size = count($id);
var_dump($size);

for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
updateLine($id[$i], $start[$i], $end[$i]);
}

function updateLine($id, $start, $end){
    var_dump($id);
    var_dump($start);
    $sql = "UPDATE `Sequence` 
            SET start='" . $start . "', fin='" . $end . "' 
            WHERE id='" . $id . "'";    
    $result=execute_query($sql);
    var_dump($sql);
}
```

Comment: Because `$id`, `$start` and `$end` in your call are handled as char arrays. What do you want to do exactly? Please elaborate a bit.

Comment: `$id $start $end` are not arrays, but you treat them as arrays?

Comment: @JvdBerg Originally they are arrays. I just simplified the example.

Comment: @YouKuper: You example does not make any sense.

Comment: Then you are getting the results you are currently because you didn't remove the subscript operators from your updateLine parameters.

Comment: @Christian Ivicevic: Please see the update.

Comment: @YouKuper - you do not want to select individual characters from your strings. Remove the array subscripts from your parameters to `updateLine`

Comment: @YouKuper: As nkr mentioned, your exmaple still doesn't make any sense because simplifying and making strings from arrays just destroys the semantics.

Comment: "Originally they are arrays." - they are probably not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested and I get no errors with the following code :

```
$id = array('2230', '2245');
$start = array('2012-10-02 11:36:13', '2012-10-15 11:36:13');
$end = array('2012-10-02 11:36:23', '2012-10-15 11:36:23');

$size = count($id);
var_dump($size);

for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){
    updateLine($id[$i], $start[$i], $end[$i]);
}

function updateLine($id, $start, $end){
    $sql = "UPDATE `Sequence` 
            SET start='" . $start . "', fin='" . $end . "' 
            WHERE id='" . $id . "'";    
    $result=execute_query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `[]` operator accesses the i-th character of a string. `i` is 0, so you get 2, 2, and 2 for the three values.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call `updateLine($id[$i], $start[$i], $end[$i])` which is completely weird. Just call it without the for loop and without the index like that `updateLine($id, $start, $end)` and you are good to go. Otherwise, as stated in my comment you only have a string (=char array) and access char by char with the indexing operator `[]` which was mentioned by other people, too.

Only if you plan to store different values in arrays like `$id = array("trololo", "blabla")` you should iterate over them like you did in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Because $id, $start, $end aren't array and array access to non array's results almost in unexpected results

You have to use something like this

```
$id = array('2230');
$start = array('2012-10-02 11:36:13');
$end = array('2012-10-02 11:36:13');
```

or remove the for loop

Comment: Yes they are. Strings can be accessed as character arrays (and traditionally were implemented as arrays of characters). Treating them as arrays is completely defined.

Comment: Yes it is, but in most cases this happen by accident